# Disable "now" line in org agenda view?

Tags: org-mode, org-agenda

**Q:** how can I disable the "now" line in an `org-mode` agenda view?

When displaying a time grid in the agenda, `org-mode` displays, by default (or so I assume), a line with the current time listed as "now":

```
Day-agenda (W03):
Monday     12 January 2015 W03
               8:00am........ ----------------
              10:00am........ ----------------
              12:00pm........ ----------------
(THIS LINE)   12:34pm........ now - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
               2:00pm........ ----------------
               4:00pm........ ----------------
               6:00pm........ ----------------
               8:00pm........ ----------------
```

I want to remove the "now" line.  How does one turn it off?  Unless I missed something, there's no obvious setting in `org-agenda-time-grid` (or related variables) to disable "now."

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try customizing `org-agenda-show-current-time-in-grid`, which defaults to `t`.